# Bind Different View Models To Each Page

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js, viewmodel

I have a site that has multiple pages with vastly different data on each page.  I would like a way to bind a different view model to each page without having to put javascript into each page.

Should I bind the view model in the load handler of my container div element?

Comment: Ok. allow me to re-word it.  I doubt that it can be re-written to not inspire a "discussion" though..  It is what it is.

Comment: the problem is that I have multiple pages that deal with vastly different data.  I do not want to use a single view model for all pages, I would like to separate concerns.  I think that I may bind a viewmodel to the container elements.

Comment: Done.  Do you have any insight?

Comment: You'll have a different viewmodel on each page you say -- that's different JavaScript, isn't it? If it's not, and you're using a generic mapping plugin of some sort, I'd imagine you could just always use ko.applyBindings to the same base viewModel (which is then modified via the mapping plugin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this will work.

```
if($('#myelement').length) {
    //Bind view model
}
```